Add 'business context' to all views Django
I've got an app handling a store, with some view of Items that are sold there and some list of Employees there etc.
Now, there will be the second (physical) store, and my application is not ready for handling more than one :)
So to my models will be added Location model, and foreign keys added to Item and Employee...
But my question is how to rebuild views ... So my view that lists all Items, should have added some filter on the top to select location and than filter list based on that selection... and Employee view the same (and all other the same)....
So - having that filter there on the top, I should set some global ('session'?) variable, and based on that filter each view? (or add it in url parameters?? or any other way?)
Please advise me how to do it an elegant way.
I've got simple function based views:
def EmployeeList(request): 
   objList = Employee.objects.all() 
   return render(request,'Employee/list.html,{'objList':objList})

And so far, not too complicated urls ;)
path('EmployeeList/', viewsEmployee.EmployeeList, name="EmployeeList"),    


Please add information (code, preferably) about what your views look like.

Sure, I can, but it will bring no value. It is simple list of objects from model...  objList = Employee.objects.all()

Okay, but is it a function-based view or a class-based view? What do your URLs look like - do you have any segmentation at all already, or is it just a single view with no path parameters?

you're right, edited.

# urls.py
path("/store", View)
path("/store/<int:pk>", View)

# views.py
def View(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        location  = Location.objects.get(pk=pk)
        employees = Employee.objects.filter(location=location)
        items     = Item.objects.filter(location=location)
    else:
        employees = Employee.objects.all()
        items     = Item.objects.all()

Then simply redirect to the appropriate URL whenever the user makes a drop-down selection.

so that /storeId/ should be added to every url in my app i believe then

Or maybe I can use session variable and no URLs are changed then ?

You probably can ... but there's a myriad of reasons why it's not recommended. You won't get good search engine SEO, your users can't have two windows open (to view two different locations) at the same time, you're exposing more of your app's internals to users (and thus, attackers) than necessary, testing and debugging becomes significantly more complex, and many more.

OK. Yes, I'm changing it in every link in templates, and every url in urls and adding to every view  as an input param, and passing it from view as return result.... what is a little painful. Just wondered if it can be done in any smarter way... to have that info available throughout the whole application.
