Django view to redirect to same url with different parameter?
I've got django app with a views (urls), that show different lists for different locations:
path('ItemList/<int:locationId>/', views.ItemList, name="ItemList"),
path('SomethingList/<int:locationId>/', views.SomethingList, name="SomethingList"),    

and then in a template I've got a menu, when I can switch between locations, ie. being in -- ItemList/2/   I can switch to location with different Id
or being in SomethingList/4/  I can switch to location with different Id
To switch location, I've got a method (which obviusly is incorrect):
def setLocation (request, newLocationId): 
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'], locationId = newLocationId)

but how can I do it, to get the current url like:
ItemList/2/
and redirect it to  ItemList/4/  (ie. to different id?)
SOLUTION SO FAR:
-well I'm not sure if it is any way pythonic or django way of solving this, but my solution so far is:
def setLocation (request, id): 
    next = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']  
    path = urlparse(next)[2] 
    match = resolve(path) 
    view, args, kwargs = resolve(path) 
    kwargs['locationId'] = id 
    return redirect(match.app_name+':'+match.url_name, **kwargs)


I guess you'd call setLocation() from a view. Is there a reason you can't pass that view's name to setLocation() along with newLocationId?

Hmm, so in that scenario, in all views of my applications I should create string with current view name and pass it to view as param. Not sure if it is optimal solution?

@andrew Just saw your edit of the OP. My code snippet does practically the same. But you said that you don't think it'd work. Now I am a bit confused what exactly you need. Can you clarify whether setLocation is called as a view (with its own request) or if it is called from another view with that view's request? How do you "switch locations"? Is it a button on the page?

Hi @CoffeeBasedLifeform. So in global index.html  I've got a list of locations (links), so that I can globally, for the whole application (no matter on which page/view I am) -  I can change location. So it is kind of global variable.   So example if I'm seeing list of items, I can switch globally to different location to see the list of items in that location and for each view the same..
It's related with:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78698816/add-business-context-to-all-views-django/78698972?noredirect=1#comment138761967_78698972

So - in genearl - from any view - I can do switch location, than it goes through setLocation (to change id in url)... - and then it should return to same view.
It's related with:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78698816/add-business-context-to-all-views-django/78698972

The request has a resolver_match attribute which you could use together with the new location id to get the url to redirect to:
def setLocation (request, newLocationId):
    view_name = request.resolver_match.view_name  # "ItemList" or "SomethingList" as per URL conf
    return redirect(reverse(view_name, kwargs={"locationId": newLocationId}))

ResolverMatch

I don't think it works. It takes current (setLocation) url, not the referrer...

Yeah, this wasn't what you were after - I realized that after I had already gone offlne. I'm not sure how you are switching between locations. If it's just a link or a button, then you can just pass the URL to the other location in the context data to the template and render the link with that URL - no redirect needed. If you want to redirect as a response to another request, then you could pass the view name to redirect to as a request parameter (either GET or POST).
